# How to align image to the left and text to the center on a Xamarin button in iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I want to align my text in the center, but the image on the left. I have tried it with HorizontalAlignment, but it aligns both. How to do it?

Comment: what's the issue u r facing? what have u tried so far? please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

I took the time to actually understand how "insets" work, and wrote my own solution.

[image: Ringotan]

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(RingotanButtonRenderer))]
namespace MyAppNamespace
{
    public class MyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();

            // Left-align the image and center the text
            // Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71044012/238419
            if (Element.ContentLayout.Position == Button.ButtonContentLayout.ImagePosition.Left)
            {
                const int imageMargin = 20; // This might need to get multiplied by the screen density, not sure yet.  I'll update this later if it does.
                nfloat imageOffset = Control.ImageView.Frame.Left - imageMargin;
                Control.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, -imageOffset, 0, imageOffset);

                nfloat imageWidth = Control.ImageView.Frame.Width + imageMargin;
                nfloat textOffset = Control.TitleLabel.Frame.Left - (imageWidth + Control.Frame.Width - Control.TitleLabel.Frame.Width) / 2;
                Control.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, -textOffset, 0, textOffset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- If you want the text to be centered on the overall button, rather than centered on the available remaining space, set `imageWidth = 0`
- If you only want this to apply to *some* buttons, create a new class that extends `Button` and set the `ExportRenderer` to that new class.  Then only use that new class where you want the text centered.
- This only works for left-aligned images, but similar math can be used for the other alignments
- There seems to be a bug where Xamarin/iOS ignores the inset if you update the button's `ImageSource` or `Text`.  I haven't been able to find a workaround to this bug yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ButtonContentLayout.ImagePosition` property:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button.buttoncontentlayout.imageposition?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Thank you, do you know how I could set it from Control in ButtonRenderer?

Comment: being in the renderer, e.NewElement / e.OldElement gives you access to the Xamarin.Forms control, and this.Control gives you access to the native control: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

Comment: This puts the image to the left of the text, but does not left-align it to the edges of the button.  This means if multiple buttons are stacked, their images will not be aligned and it looks like garbage.

Answer (score -1):

> do you know how I could set it from Control in ButtonRenderer?

You can change the `ImageEdgeInsets` and `TitleEdgeInsets` of the button in the renderer to change the image and title position:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(Button), typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]
namespace App650.iOS
{
    public class MyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                //Control is UIButton
                Control.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, Control.Frame.Size.Width - (Control.ImageView.Frame.Size.Width), 0, 0);
                Control.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, Control.ImageView.Frame.Size.Width);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately all three values Control.Frame.Size.Width, Control.ImageView.Frame.Size.Width and Control.ImageView.Frame.Size.Width are 0. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Try to call those code in the layoutSubviews method.

Comment: Like this? It is still 0.                                                                                                        override
        public  void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            Control.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, Control.Frame.Size.Width - (Control.ImageView.Frame.Size.Width), 0, 0);
            Control.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, Control.ImageView.Frame.Size.Width);

        }

Comment: Check if (e.NewElement != null), see my updated answer.

Comment: This is still wrong. All of the `Size.Width` values are 0 when this runs. Even if you correctly run it in `LayoutSubviews`, the math is completely wrong - it moves the image all the way to the right, and does nothing to the label.