# iOS button Image position like Android

Tags: c#, button, xamarin.forms

In general, such a problem is how to make the alignment of icons on iOS the same as on android (at the beginning of the button). Maybe use custom renderer, how?
Android:
[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rER0l.png)
iOS:
[iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Y4A.png)

Comment: We always use pure XAML to create our own button designs and have a transparent empty button on top of it to have the touch handles.

Comment: @Depechie, but then we will not have information that the user pressed or released the button in order to perform the corresponding animations.

Answer (score 0):

Tyr to use [Button.ButtonContentLayout.ImagePosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button.buttoncontentlayout.imageposition?view=xamarin-forms), the ContentLayout property has two values separated by a comma. First is the position we want the image to appear in defined by the ImagePosition enumerator we can set the image to the Top, Left, Right or Bottom of the button. The second parameter is the space we want between the button text and the icon.

```
 <Button 
            ContentLayout="Left,30"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Image="cactus_24px"
            Text="Left icon" />
```

Comment: but in this case, you will need to select the distance for each button individually. I would like a more versatile solution.

Comment: @APXANGEL You can also use Button custom render to add image on left, please take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939743/how-to-align-image-to-the-left-and-text-to-the-center-on-a-xamarin-button-in-ios

Comment: I tried that code, but I don't understand what distance is calculated there (from what to what). Without modification, that code gives the following result: [link](https://a.radikal.ru/a03/2108/e0/449c6f1246ac.png)